# How do I create a user in AD and Okta?

Tags: okta, okta-api

How do I automatically create a user in Active Directory, at the same time as creating the user in Okta. Is there an API/SDK to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Create User](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#create-user) call to create a User in Okta. Additionally, you can [add this user](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/groups.html#add-user-to-group) to a group.

Upon membership in this specific group which should be configured with AD as the provisioning target, the group members are provisioned in AD (or any other application as per configuration).